# Разбить строку после второй запятой

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, re

Было:

```
text = "Екатеринбург (г),Славинская (ул),д.17,кв.161"
```

Стало:

```
text1 = "Екатеринбург (г),Славинская (ул)," 
text2 = "д.17,кв.161"
```

Пока не понимаю, как это можно регулярками сделать.

Comment: Я вам исправил форматирование. Вроде всегда такое и было. А перевод строки в обычном тексте делается двумя пробелами в конце строки. Почитайте про маркап, там много интересного.

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно было, писал все сплошь, потому не обращал внимания

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам обязательно регулярки нужны? Можно и без них довольно просто сделать:

```py
text = "Екатеринбург (г),Славинская (ул),д.17,кв.161"
text_split = text.split(',')
text1 = ','.join(text_split[:2])
text2 = ','.join(text_split[2:])
```

Comment: Необязательно, спасибо! сейчас перепроверю

Answer (score 1):

как вариант можете попробовать такой код, он создаст вам словарь:

```
from re import fullmatch

txt = "Екатеринбург (г),Славинская (ул),д.17,кв.161"
m = fullmatch(r'(?P<text1>.*?,.*?),(?P<text2>.*)', txt).groupdict()

>>> m
# {'text1': 'Екатеринбург (г),Славинская (ул)', 'text2': 'д.17,кв.161'}
```